# Maxima And Minima At The Critical Points

Tags: derivatives

The function $f(x)=x^3$ has the derivative $3x^2$ which is equal to $0$ at $x=0$ but the function $f(x)=x^3$ has neither maxima nor minima at that point. How is this possible?

Comment: Because the rate of change of $f(x)$ is instantaneously zero at this point. It is a point of inflection.

Comment: But Fermat's theoram says that if $f'$ is defined and equal to $0$ then $f$ has either maxima or minima

Comment: "Fermat's theorem gives only a necessary condition for extreme function values, as some stationary points are inflection points (not a maximum or minimum)." - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points))

Answer (score -1):

Because $f$ increases, but $y=0$ is a tangent to the graph of $f$ at $(0,0)$.

$(0,0)$ is an inflection point.

Comment: Can down-voter explain us why did you do it?

Answer (score -1):

The critical values $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$ are obtained by setting $f'(x)=0$ or $f'(x)$ is undefined.

The uses of these critical values are to know:

- The maximum and minimum; if $f'(x_n)=0$ or $f'(x_n)$ is undefined. [Provided that the sign of $f'(x)$ changes before and after $x_n$].
- The point of inflection (when the concavity changes); if $f''(x_n)=0$ or $f''(x_n)$ is undefined. [Provided that the sign of $f''(x)$ changes before and after $x_n$].

---

Here, in your problem, $f'(x)=0$ at $x=0$, but the sign of $f'(x)$ does not change before and after $x=0$. Hence neither a maximum nor a minimum at $x=0$.

---

However, since $f''(x)=0$ at $x=0$, and the sign of $f''(x)$ changes before and after $x=0$, this means that $f(x)$ has an inflection point at $x=0$.